# Glide loads wrong image size

Tags: android, android-glide

I use simple:

```
Glide.with(this).load(logoPath).apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform()).into(businessIcon)
```

Size of `logoPath` on server is 48*48, when I put `wrap_content` attribute on `ImageView` dimensions, final image is 1280*1280.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you referring to the View size or resolution?

Comment: I just want Glide to download image as it is, for instance 48*48 px, View size is wrap content.

Comment: Yeah, it makes sense. What is `logoPath` type? Are you getting it directly from server or keep local file?

Comment: From server directly

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be some misunderstanding in what `Glide` gets from the server.

It is just regular file, and it will be fetched as-is, it is extremely unlikely somebody could get higher resolution image by downloading. 
(If you really can, you could make a lot of money )

So the actual problem is how this image file is displayed.

You could use `ImageView` attribute `android:scaleType="center"` to force no scaling to be performed.

You could also download the Image, convert it to Bitmap and get its attributes. Something simmilar to this.

```
 BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
 options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
 BitmapFactory.decodeFile(logoPath, options);
 int imageHeight = options.outHeight;
 int imageWidth = options.outWidth;
```

And then use  these values for fixed dimensions in `Glide`s method `.override()`